# How to show that if $f$ is a convex function, then the limit $\underset{t \rightarrow 0^+}{lim}\frac{f(x+ty)-f(x)}{t}$ exists?

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis, convexity-inequality

> Let $E$ be a Banach space, and $U \subset E$ an open non empty set. If $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a convex function, show that this limist exists:
>   $$\partial _y^+f(x) = \underset{t \rightarrow 0^+ }{lim}\frac{f(x+ty)-f(x)}{t} $$
>   My approach was to define the function $T_f(x_1,x_2)= \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1}$. As $f$ is convex, $T_f$ increase by each of its variables. Thus we have: $$T_f(x-ty, x) \leq T_f(x, x+ty) \leq T_f(x+ty, x+y) $$

But this doesn't seem to be able to answer the question fully because the left inequality does exist, as a convex function has right derivative, but I seem to be unable to find an inequality that would show the existence of the left derivative.

Comment: Once you know the function $g(t)=\frac1t(f(x+ty)-f(x))$ is nondecreasing on $t>0$, you only need to show that $g(t)$ is bounded below uniformly on $t>0$ to deduce that its limit at $0^+$ exists (and is finite). So, any lower bound uniform on $t>0$?

Comment: Indeed, use Jensen to find the lower bound by making $x$ the midpoint.